# Sum rows sql for each month

Tags: sql, sum

I am trying make a SQL query but after 12h trying I decided to open a topic, maybe someone can help me:

My table is "transactions":

```
id | client_id |         date          | income |    
1  | 100       | 2014-07-14 10:25:06   | 100    |    
2  | 101       | 2014-07-11 20:25:06   | 200    |
3  | 102       | 2014-08-01 22:25:06   | 150    |
4  | 101       | 2014-08-01 22:25:06   | 300    |
5  | 101       | 2014-08-01 22:25:06   | 300    |
```

And I need to calculate the sum of all "income" for each month (January, February, March ...)

From the above table it will give:

```
July: 300 EUR 
August: 750 EUR
```

Someone can help me to find the right SQL?

I need print it with php, what code should I do?
Really I need your help.

Comment: You need to group by month. There is no generic SQL solution, as date time functions are not unified by ANSI standard and implemented differently for each RDBMS. Therefore, you need to tell what database you are using

Comment: @cha: actually it *is* defined by the standard: `extract(month from date_column)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: thanks for that. Good to know. SQL Server though does not support it

Comment: @cha: but we don't know if FullDISK is using SQL Server.

Comment: No, we don't, but we have already decoded that they use PHP :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what SQL format you're using, nor do I have an environment in front of me, but it will be something like this.

```
SELECT derivedTable.MonthDate, sum(derivedTable.income)
FROM
(
  SELECT FORMAT(inp.DATE, 'mmyy') as MonthDate, income FROM transactions
) derivedTable(MonthDate, income)
GROUP BY derivedTable.MonthDate
```

Comment: That depends on what language you are using. You print the row then go to the next record.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a function to truncate the date and group on this. This function is different per DBMS. In Oracle it would be something like this:

```
SELECT TRUNC(date,'YYYY-MON'), SUM(income) FROM table1
GROUP BY TRUNC(date,'YYYY-MON')
```

And in MySQL for example you can use `DATE_FORMAT()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATEPART(MONTH,[DATE]) AS 'DATE', SUM(income) AS 'Sum' from #transactions
Group BY DATEPART(MONTH,[DATE])
```

Comment: How can I do? I need print this query in php. Can you help me find the code?